# nginx: serve static content with alias url

Tags: django, web-services, nginx, static, http-status-code-404

I'm writing a web service using django and rest-framework and I use nginx as my web server.

The clients will work with the API using standard REST methods. One of the modules lets users to upload a photo and the service changes the name to random string and saves it under: `/home/myProject/files/user-content/`, like:

`/home/myProject/files/user-content/bb7dfb34336d4b638e50040cf91b8d9d.png`

At the API level everything works just fine. But I want the users to be able to get the files they have uploaded from: `/image/:filename` like:
`http://mydomain/images/bb7dfb34336d4b638e50040cf91b8d9d.png`

To achieve that, I this is the configuration I have for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    error_page   404        /index.html;

    root /home/webworker/landingpage/Page;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
                 proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }

     location ~ ^/images/(.*)$ {
             alias /home/myProject/files/user-content/$1;
             access_log on;
             index index.html;
             autoindex off;
             gzip_static on;
             # expires max;
             sendfile off;
             add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
     }
```

}

nginx service starts with no error, but entering the URL I think should work returns with `404 not found`. BTW the files have read permission for all users.

Comment: Have you looked at the nginx logs - they might explain what isn't working.

Comment: @Alasdair yes I have, there was nothing helpful...

Answer (score 2):

replace this line

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*)$ {
```

with

```
location /images/ {
```

This should satisfy your need.

Comment: Could you check nginx access and error logs? and can you make sure that the image is there? @RezaShayestehpour

Comment: as I said, the image is in the folder I'm pointing to and has the proper permissions. And about the log: the ones related to getting the image are: `MYIPADDRESS - - [17/Sep/2015:08:11:29 -0400] "GET /images/bb7dfb34336d4b638e50040cf91b8d9d.png HTTP/1.1" 404 151 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.8 Safari/600.8.9"` and no errors, just some warning about changing localhost to 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: Could you also try to change the alias to alias /home/myProject/files/user-content/ ; ? And for test just comment every other line. I feel there might be something wrong with your addressing system... @RezaShayestehpour

Comment: Okay the problem isn't with this configuration file, it lies somewhere else. @RezaShayestehpour